# Passing Variables through Nested Shell Scripts

Tags: shell

I have a simple loop in my Shell Script and want to be able to run another loop for each file in the directory...right now I am just asking for it to echo each file but I do want to do more with each file, but want to figure this out first...

```
for dir in "$@/"*
do
folder=$(basename "$dir")
path="/Users/wme/Desktop/test3/"
if [ ! -d "$path$folder" ]; then
mkdir "$path$folder"
mkdir "$path$folder/mp4"
mkdir "$path$folder/mov"
mkdir "$path$folder/ogg"
mkdir "$path$folder/webm"
mkdir "$path$folder/img"
fi
for file in "$dir/"*
    echo $file
done
done
```

So essentially it is finding all the directories creating a folder structure for those folders, and now I need to go and process the movies in each of those folders...but I get an error when I try to do the second nested loop, what am I doing wrong?

Also it should be noted I am running this in Automator so it doesn't really give me an error, just says action failed

Comment: You forgot `do` in your second loop.

Comment: Jesus Christ, I spent 20 min trying to make sure I wasnt asking a dumb question...Thanks!

Comment: Always best to test scripts outside of Automator, always revert to the shell when debugging scripts or tracking down errors.

Answer (score 0):

You will also have an issue with your first for loop. `"$@/"*` will expand to `$1 $2 ... $n/*`, not `$1/* $2/* ... $n/*`. You'll need

```
path="/Users/wme/Desktop/test3"
for dir in "$@"; do
    for subdir in "$dir/"*; do
        folder=$(basename "$subdir")

        if [ ! -d "$path/$folder" ]; then
            for ftype in mp4 mov ogg webm img; do
                mkdir -p "$path/$folder/$ftype"
            done
        fi
        for file in "$subdir/"*
           echo $file
        done
done
```